# Backbone.js: Model inheritance causes shared data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, prototypal-inheritance

I've been banging my head on this one for the last two days. For some reason backbone is sharing parent instance data across inherited child models. Heres an example:

```
var Base = Backbone.Model.extend({

  index : []

});

var Group = Base.extend({

  initialize : function() {
    this.index.push('from group');
  }

});


var User = Base.extend({

  initialize : function() {
    this.index.push('from user');
  }

});


var user = new User();
console.log(user.index); // ['from user']


var group = new Group();
console.log(group.index) // ['from user', 'from group']
```

---

What I'm looking for is:

```
console.log(user.index); // ['from user']
console.log(group.index) // ['from group']
```

Any insights?

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are experiencing is essentially a byproduct of the way JS passes objects (or arrays) by reference and not by value.  If you want index to be different for User and Group, simply instantiate it as an array in your initialize function.

```
var Base = Backbone.Model.extend({

initialize: function() {
  this.index = [];
}


});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was really hoping `extend()` would avoid this issue by cloning objects / arrays. It looks like this practice of defining arrays and objects in the parent class should be avoided because it could lead to unintended consequences.

Comment: There are reasons to define objects or arrays in the classes like this, but your intent is to use index as an instance variable such that it's unique to each instance vs being shared between all instances like class variables.  If you want instance variables then yes you shouldn't define them in the object passed to extend, but if you want class variable then yes its fine to do so.  Perfectly fine to define the instance variables in the parent's constructor as Skylar has shown too.

Answer (score 6):

The index member is like a class variable in that it's in the prototype chain of Base and thus shared by all instances just as the methods it contains are also shared.  Try switching the order of the instantiating User and Group.  Now what does index contain?  It's reverse right?  That's because they are sharing everything the object passed to extend.

In order for it to be an instance variable you'll need to instantiate it in a constructor for Base, and have each subclass call that constructor from their respective constructors.  Like:

```
var Base = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
       this.index = [];
    }
});

var User = Base.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        Base.prototype.initialize.call( this );
        this.index.push('User');
    }
});

// repeat it for group.
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer. This is another way to solve the problem.